# Need cache per request capability in Java

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am developing REST APIs using Java Spring framework.

When calling these APIs, I have a need to check for permissions, where I will need to make a call to the DB to get the permission data. The thing is, there are multiple areas checking for permission in a single request, and I do not want to make multiple calls to the DB, so I intent to cache the permission data just for that single request.

I have tried creating a request scoped bean, which works, but not for all cases. There are times where the request scoped bean cannot be created, for example when running a scheduled code using @Scheduled annotation, simply because it is not a request. Another case is when checking for permissions using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, the bean is also not yet created at that time.

So, I looked into another possible solution, which is this: https://github.com/rinoto/spring-request-cache. If I use this solution, I will need to remove the cache from threadLocal every time an operation is complete. I am not very comfortable of using this solution since I'm not an expert in Java, and I've read that it is not recommended to use threadLocal as cache.

What's the best way to achieve my goal? My ask is simple, cache some data only for that request. Is there any library that supports it?

I find it hard to believe that my ask is not a normal use case, or is it not a normal use case?

Comment: How about use cache service such as redis , memcached ?

Comment: „I find it hard to believe that my ask is not a normal use case, or is it not a normal use case?„ Please avoid this kind of comments. You are visibly frustrated with something that in my opinion is common and simple programming problem. This is not related to any framework or db technology. ThreadLocal is indeed one of possible answers.

Comment: @MateuszStefek I apologize if that comment offended you in anyway. I am not frustrated. I am just trying to find the best solution. As you said, this is a simple and common problem, yet I can't find a straight answer to it. ThreadLocal is a possible solution, but is it risky? Just see a proposed answer by Maheshkumar, suggesting that I can use ThreadLocal, and caisil commented that memory leak can happen. In Spring Cache, we can set the cache's TTL, and I just hoped that there is a configuration to tell the cache to expire after each request.

Comment: Use a normal caching library like Guava or cache2k and set a TTL between 5 minutes and one hour. For permissions it is usually okay if it takes a bit of time until the revoke is done. If that is a problem, you could add a REST API for the permission revoke to remove it from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThreadLocal` as a cache in this case. No need to clear. As per the documentation

> Each thread holds an implicit reference to its copy of a thread-local variable as long as the thread is alive and the {@code ThreadLocal} instance is accessible; after a thread goes away, all of its copies of thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection (unless other references to these copies exist).

eg: `ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> THREAD_LOCAL_DATA = ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new)`

Comment: For webservice using thread pool, the threads are long live. It will cause memory leak if not remove explicitly.

Comment: So I guess if I have to go the ThreadLocal way, I must clear the cache after each operation then?

Comment: @DhinneshJeevan, ThreadLocal data will be garbage collected automatically after thread completed. No need to remove manually.